# (the, Ø) rates: article usage

Tags: articles, determiners, zero-article

A quote [from The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/business/2013/aug/14/uk-unemployment-claimant-count):

> The Bank of England, under its new governor Mark Carney, has promised
>   that **interest rates** will stay at their record low level of 0.5% until
>   **the unemployment rate** drops below 7%. Threadneedle Street's experts
>   expect that will not happen until 2016; but upbeat news from the
>   labour market will fuel fears in financial markets that **rates** will
>   have to rise sooner than the Bank expects.

Why is there no definite article before *interest rates* and again before *rates*? 
Is it because with the definite article, *interest rate* would refer not to a metric or gauge, but to some implied specific figure, e.g. 8%, and *interest rates* would respectfully refer to a string of figures (8%, 9%...) ?

It is strange to see the third mention of *rates* without an article, because the word may point an all kinds of rates, there are a lot of metrics in economics.

The *unemployment rate* understandably takes THE, 'cause the head noun is singular.

What if we rewrite the paragraph using the singular form:

> The Bank of England, under its new governor Mark Carney, has promised
>   that **the interest rate** will stay at its record low level of 0.5% until
>   **the unemployment rate** drops below 7%. Threadneedle Street's experts
>   expect that will not happen until 2016; but upbeat news from the
>   labour market will fuel fears in financial markets that **the rate** will
>   have to rise sooner than the Bank expects.

Would this look OK to the native speaker?

Comment: It looks okay (syntactically), but I think the original reads better. If the inconsistency bothers you, I'd suggest rewording it by using **unemployment rates** in the plural.

Comment: Inconsistency is OK, I'm just trying to train myself to pay attention to articles by pre-cutting them from a text and then trying to reinstate them in proper places; all with mixed success and much amazement as to the principles used by native speakers in their article usage choices.

Comment: The basic "rules" about articles aren't always hard and fast, as you are learning. Why do little children sing "There were 10 in **the** bed" but "Rub-a-dub dub, three men in **a** tub"? Because, every once in a while, it really doesn't matter which article you use. It's largely based on context; in this case financial experts have their own linguistic quirks, much like other professions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"the interest rate" would means there is just one interest rate, but the Bank of England maintains a number of interest rates. That said, the rest of that sentence indicates a value of 0.5% and as you suggest that would mean there is just one rate (or that all interest rates are set at 0.5%, which is most likely not the case).

So I would suggest that there is just one interest rate, but the reason is it given as a plural is that this interest rate applies to all the bank's customers. So maybe it means "the rates for all customers" in other words "the customers' rates", and again that's a plural rates not a singular, since each customer has a rate even though they are all 0.5%

I think I might have tied myself in knots here, but I think what I'm saying is the truth. As an Englishman and someone working in banking I know "rates" sounds correct, I've just never thought why it is so.

Comment: I'm no financial expert, but I believe there is a single interest rate (in the U.S., it's set by "the Fed", meaning the Federal Reserve). Other banks offer loans _based on_ that rate, but not necessarily _at_ that rate. It's an index of sorts; other interest rates fluctuate along with "the" interest rate. I agree that "rates" is commonly heard when it comes to financial news, possibly because these rates change over time, and possibly because so many of them are interrelated.